# Google application specific passwords, 2-step verification, Gmail and Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

I download my gmail into Outlook.  Will Outlook ask for a new password every time it tries to log in to gmail, which is every 5 minutes?  That is a deal killer for me.

The setup documentation was ambiguous.

Comment: In my experience, app-specific passwords are a one-time thing, but I haven't used them much.

Comment: @Shinrai Application specific passwords are rather a "one-app"  thing. You deploy them for, let's say Outlook, and then keep them saved there. You don't have to enter a new one each time, though.

Comment: @slhck - I assumed that was implied by the name! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Application-specific passwords are meant to be 'single application', but are not 'single use'. If Outlook is set to remember your password, once you enter your user name and the application-specific password you have generated, it will not ask you to enter it again.

Comment: Excellent, that was really the point of my question - it is not single use.  I understood the rest, I was just afraid it was going to keep wanting a new password on each login.

Answer (score 4):

No. In order to set up your account, Outlook will ask you for a username and password.

Instead of your regular Google password, you need to supply an application specific password, which you can generate [from your Accounts page](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens?hl=en). This password will work just like your normal Google password, so if you save that, you won't have to enter it all the time.

Watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMabEyrtPRg&t=2m13s) for more info.

In essence, two factor authentication (where it's asking you for your verification code) only works if the client software also supports it. If it doesn't, signing in will be the same as always, but only using the application specific password.

Answer (score 1):

Application specific passwords would be applied to POP or IMAP in your case.  This password is not asked for periodically as you noted. See: [Signing in using application-specific passwords - Accounts Help](http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185833)

I suspect something is not correct with your account or credentials being passed.

- [2-Step auth related troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1185133)
- [Other troubleshooting steps recommended](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78754) would be supply captcha